# Linux: Using "clone3" and "waitid"

Tags: linux, process, system-calls, wait

I'm trying to learn about forking/cloning processes using the "clone3" system call. I have read the manual pages to understand it. Other than the manual pages, I was able to find only [ONE](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-api/msg37703.html) example of how to use it online (on the internet) and it doesn't seem to work. In addition, the example uses "waitpid" libc function instead of the "waitid" system call that I want to use. In conclusion, I have modified the example to "transform" it to the following code:

```c
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#endif
#include <bits/types/struct_rusage.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef CLONE_PIDFD
#define CLONE_PIDFD 0x00001000
#endif

#ifndef __NR_clone3
#define __NR_clone3 -1
struct clone_args {
  __aligned_u64 flags;
  __aligned_u64 pidfd;
  __aligned_u64 child_tid;
  __aligned_u64 parent_tid;
  __aligned_u64 exit_signal;
  __aligned_u64 stack;
  __aligned_u64 stack_size;
  __aligned_u64 tls;
};
#endif

static pid_t sys_clone3(struct clone_args *args) { return syscall(__NR_clone3, args, sizeof(struct clone_args)); }
static int sys_waitid(
  idtype_t type, id_t id, siginfo_t* info,
  struct rusage* usage, int options)
{
  return syscall(247, type, id, info, usage, options);
}

int value = 10;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct clone_args args = {
    .flags = CLONE_VM,
    .exit_signal = SIGCHLD,
  };

  int pid = sys_clone3(&args);
  if (pid < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s - Failed to create new process\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (pid == 0) {
    printf("Child process with pid %d\n", getpid());
    value = 20;
    printf("Value changed!");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }

  printf("Parent process received child's pid %d\n", pid);

  siginfo_t info;
  struct rusage usage;
  int wait_status = sys_waitid(P_ALL, 0, &info, &usage, __WALL);
  if (wait_status == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to wait on child process (%d)\n", errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("Tha value is: %d\n", value);

  return 0;
}
```

It stil doesn't work however. the block of the cloned process does not seem to be executed for some reason.... Also, if I run the program mulitple times in a row, at some point, it will fail to wait for the process with exit code "22". The error code is called `EINVAL` which means that the options for "waitid" were invalid (as stated by the man pages). But how is that possible to not get executed every single time but randomly happen? I'm so confused...

I think that it will also be a great question given the fact that there is very little info about "clone3" online. It should also be noted that I need these two specifically. I am writing a system's library and I want to learn how to use them. Also, I am creating my own "waitid" version because the version of "libc" does not make use of the "rusage" struct, so I want to be 100% sure that there isn't something else going on that I cannot see. Thank you!

I expected the program to execute the block of the newly created thread.

Comment: Are you expecting value to change in the parent process?

Comment: I am. But that's not the problem. For now, I just want the thread (child process) that was created to execute its code. Both this code and the example I linked do not work. And just to be more clear, when I say "its code", I'm talking about line 54 to line 59 where it checks if "pid" is **0** (which should be the case for the child).

Comment: Where did 247 come from?

Comment: waitid appears to be 95 https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h#L262

Comment: From every source I could find online, they list "247" as the number for "waitid" on x86_64. "95" is listed as the number for ARM64. The source you provided does not seem to specify Arch (unless I'm blind, of course, as it has happened in the past).

Look some sources I found:

[1](https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/)
[2](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md)
[3](https://marcin.juszkiewicz.com.pl/download/tables/syscalls.html)
[4](https://arm64.syscall.sh/)
[5](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/)